# How do I use a function result as my alias?

Tags: sql

I am wondering if it is possible to use an SQL function to name the column of a query. As a simple example:

```
SELECT id AS SUBSTR('xAlias', 2) FROM foo
```

should theoretically return

```
Alias
------
...
results
...
```

If we can, which databases would this be available for? If not, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no SQL way in any major DBMS product to support this.

To name PIVOT columns in Oracle, [`for name in.. as`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816771/columns-in-oracle-pivot) seems like the best option.
Apart from that, it's over to dynamic SQL.

---

#### Original answer below

To name the column of a query, the ANSI standard is simply to add the new name after the column (derived or base) prepended by "AS":

```
SELECT id, field1, field2 * qty FROM foo
```

All columns renamed below:

```
SELECT id AS RenamedID, field1 AS Col1, field2 * qty AS ExtendedTotal FROM foo
```

This standard works for pretty much all major database systems.
There are some vendor specific variations, such as SQL Server allowing the equal sign

```
SELECT RenamedID=id FROM foo
```

And most DBMS allow the omission of the "AS" keyword

```
SELECT id RenamedID FROM foo
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I know that columns can be renamed to predetermined strings such as "foo", "field1" or "qty". But instead of using a predetermined string, can I call some kind of function such as SUBSTR, LEFT, or even a date?

Comment: Then the answer is that AFAIK no database supports this. What problem do you envisage this solving?

Comment: I am currently using a vendor which does not support the `PIVOT` statement (an older version of Oracle), so I must select from a `DECODE` function. At the moment, the column has an ugly name, and I would like to rename the column to the appropriate date that the column represents. But I can't get Oracle to rename my column to `TRUNC(SYSDATE  - x)`.

Comment: You may need to look at dynamic SQL (PL/SQL) then

Comment: Thanks. PIVOT would have been the best option, but dynamic SQL should work.

Answer (score 3):

That's a weird requirement and I think no DBMS would support that. I did the test anyway and here are the results:

This doesn't work in SQL Server 2008, MySQL 5 nor PostgreSQL 9 (they share the same sintax):

```
SELECT id AS left('xAlias', 2) FROM table
```

In Oracle 11g and SQLite 3 this failed too:

```
SELECT id AS substr('xAlias', 1, 2) FROM table
```

I bet you won't find any that supports that :P

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL and generate the query in that manner, but I don't think there is a way to do that without string building. I would imagine all major DBMS's would support dynamic SQL.