# Creating an Alias using formula in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to create an column alias using a formula ? for instance :

```
select name, values AS MONTH(getDate()) from someTable where date>getDate()
```

so that i could get AUGUST ( or 08 or 8, depending on wow i would format) as column alias ?

Comment: This is only possible using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59062/how-can-i-dynamically-alias-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267148/how-do-i-use-a-function-result-as-my-alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the data in each row could be different (and therefore the formulas result), and the column name must be unique for the entire data set.

Comment: i know that, but what i have is a table with 12 columns with values filtered by month, from current month to 12 months back, so i would have something like Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug ... but since all 12 columns are filtered based on current date, if i do this in september all columns headers should shift a month .. and width fixed columns alias i wouldn't be able to do that ...